# Do magic weapons automagically change size based on the user?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

From the PRD:

> When an article of **magic clothing or jewelry** is discovered, most of the time size shouldn't be an issue. Many magic **garments** are made to be easily adjustable, or they adjust themselves magically to the wearer. Size should not keep characters of various kinds from using **magic items**.

And then it also gives chances of getting various sizes of armor and weapons...

What should I take from this? Do *all* magic items resize appropriately, or is it only wearable stuff?

Assuming there's no official/RAW answer, what are suggestions to this issue, knowing that I'd rather have such loot be used rather than sold.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Magic items in general don't resize, no. Clothing and jewelry are the exceptions (as stated in the text you quote), simply as a matter of game convenience.

Answer (score 7):

Weapons and Armor are exceptions. This is true for mundane and magic weapons. Weapon size determines things like damage, [and there's a bunch of rules for it](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/equipment.html):

> Weapon Size: Every weapon has a size category. This designation
>   indicates the size of the creature for which the weapon was designed.
>
> A weapon's size category isn't the same as its size as an object.
>   Instead, a weapon's size category is keyed to the size of the intended
>   wielder. In general, a light weapon is an object two size categories
>   smaller than the wielder, a one-handed weapon is an object one size
>   category smaller than the wielder, and a two-handed weapon is an
>   object of the same size category as the wielder.
>
> Inappropriately Sized Weapons: A creature can't make optimum use of a
>   weapon that isn't properly sized for it. A cumulative –2 penalty
>   applies on attack rolls for each size category of difference between
>   the size of its intended wielder and the size of its actual wielder.
>   If the creature isn't proficient with the weapon, a –4 nonproficiency
>   penalty also applies.
>
> The measure of how much effort it takes to use a weapon (whether the
>   weapon is designated as a light, one-handed, or two-handed weapon for
>   a particular wielder) is altered by one step for each size category of
>   difference between the wielder's size and the size of the creature for
>   which the weapon was designed. For example, a Small creature would
>   wield a Medium one-handed weapon as a two-handed weapon. If a weapon's
>   designation would be changed to something other than light,
>   one-handed, or two-handed by this alteration, the creature can't wield
>   the weapon at all.

Armor doesn't work differently based on size, but its costs and weights change. See the table "Armor for Unusual Creatures" [on the equipment page](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/equipment.html).

That these two have their own rules for sizing and are not mentioned in the rule about magic items resizing makes it clear that they don't automatically resize. In addition, the [rules for creating magic weapons](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/magicItems/weapons.html) say this:

> Weapons for Unusually Sized Creatures: The cost of weapons for
>   creatures who are neither Small nor Medium varies (see Equipment). The
>   cost of the masterwork quality and any magical enhancement remains the
>   same.

When you're making magic weapons or armor, you have to pay the extra cost to make the base item for large (or larger) creatures. When making something like a ring or cloak, you don't have to worry about that because they resize.

(I don't know if Pathfinder has it, but 3.5 had a "sizing" magic weapon property that would allow a weapon to resize to its wielder.)