# The Effect of Size on Using Magic Items?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

By RAW, can a Diminutive creature use a Medium-sized Wand?  Can a Huge creature use said Wand?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/29708/do-magic-weapons-automagically-change-size-based-on-the-user

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A magic device doesn't have a size attribute, any creature who can carry it can use it.

It may have dimensions and weight, but these don't affect your ability to use it, only your ability to lift/carry/move/stow/etc it.  Arguably, even if a wand was too heavy for you to lift, you could still use it by holding it on the ground.

If the designers intended for size to matter with magic devices, they would have descriptors and tables for what would change, much like the size attribute on weapons.

There is no RAW for this, this is a case of "Common Sense" rules - nothing would reasonably restrict a creature from using any size magic device, except weight.

For reference, the [page](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wands) that describes a wand's physical characteristics says:

> Physical Description: A wand is 6 to 12 inches long, 1/4 inch thick, and weighs no more than 1 ounce. Most wands are wood, but some are bone, metal, or even crystal. A typical wand has Armor Class 7, 5 hit points, hardness 5, and a break DC of 16.

Comment: So, basically, any creature can carry around any magic item in as long as they have the carrying capacity to use it - as far as the rules are concerned at any rate?

Comment: @user3735278 that is right.  Of course, they still need the skill to use it (if applicable)

Comment: Maybe not _"carrying capacity"_ but _"reasonable ability to carry"_. And this _does_ kind of make sense. Imagine I decided to make a defensive tower with a Fireball wand infused in a tree trunk. The wand part would limit the possible users and the tree trunk part would limit the people who could carry it :)

Comment: @user3735278 Not *all* magic items (See the linked question).  All magic items that aren't weapons or armor.